# how to add an action to a UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView iOS7.1

Tags: xcode5, action, uibarbuttonitem, ios7.1

I use this code for getting this two buttons on right side of navigationBar:

this is my ViewController.m code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (!functions) functions = [[Functions alloc]init];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [functions returnUserProfilewithMethodToOpenMenu:@"openPopupUserProfile:"];
}
```

this is my Functions.m code:

```
-(NSArray *)returnUserProfilewithMethodToOpenMenu:(NSString *)stringMethod{

    UIImage *image      = [UIImage imageNamed:USER_PICTURE];
    UIButton *button    = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.bounds       = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width + 2, image.size.height + 2);
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    UIBarButtonItem *imageButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    [imageButton setAction:NSSelectorFromString(stringMethod)];


    UIBarButtonItem *nameButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:USER_NAME] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:NSSelectorFromString(stringMethod)];

    return [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: imageButton, nameButton, nil];
}


-(IBAction)openPopupUserProfile:(id)sender{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard        = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"]){
        if (!userProfilePopOver || !userProfilePopOver.popoverVisible){
            MenuPerfilUsuarioVC *controller     = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuPerfilUsuarioVC"];
            controller.title = @"";

            userProfilePopOver                = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
            userProfilePopOver.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [CustomPopoverBackgroundView class];

            [userProfilePopOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            [userProfilePopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            userProfilePopOver = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my result:

[image]

When I touch the button with the username, it opens a popup with a menu, two buttons...
I want to have it all in one button: image + text so I changed it to this

```
-(NSArray *)returnUserProfilewithMethodToOpenMenu:(NSString *)stringMethod{
    UIImage *image      = [UIImage imageNamed:USER_PICTURE];
    UIButton *button    = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.bounds       = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width + 100, image.size.height);
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:[@" " stringByAppendingString:USER_NAME] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(stringMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *imageButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    return [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: imageButton, nil];
}
```

[image]

but when I touch the button I get this error:

```
> 2014-03-26 18:01:18.445 Proto[3165:60b] -[UIButton view]: unrecognized
> selector sent to instance 0x1657dfe0 2014-03-26 18:01:18.449
> Proto[3165:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton view]: unrecognized
> selector sent to instance 0x1657dfe0'
> *** First throw call stack: (0x2f35dfd3 0x3a007ccf 0x2f361967 0x2f360253 0x2f2af7f8 0x320b6307 0xde71d 0x31baf057 0x31baeff7
> 0x31baefd1 0x31b9a737 0x31baea4f 0x31bae721 0x31ba96eb 0x31b7e8ed
> 0x31b7cf97 0x2f32925b 0x2f32872b 0x2f326f1f 0x2f291f4f 0x2f291d33
> 0x341c4663 0x31bdd16d 0xdd445 0x3a514ab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating
> with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

how to make it work?

Comment: show what the initWithCustomView code is

Comment: sure gonna update my post